# Could not call java function from Jenkinsfile. MultipleCompilationError exception

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

How to call Java class function in a Jenkinsfile?

We have a class A under package A , and in Jenkins file I am trying to call a functionA by creating a new object and have called the import in Jenkinsfile.

But getting error on new operator in jenkinsfile. Error as follow

```
   Org.codehaus.groovy.control.MutlipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed :
```

WorkflowScript: 47: Unable to resolve class A
@line , column

We placed java class Under src- main - java >

Java.class:
Package A
Class A :
Method A

Jenkinsfile :

Import Package A.ClassA.*
Pipeline{
....
Stage('init'){

```
        ClassA test = new ClassA();
        test.methodA();
```

I get below error on (new)

Org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException : startup failed :
WorkflowScript: 49: unable to resolve class A @line

```
       ClassA test = new ClassA();
                      ^
```

Any help please .

Comment: ok .... what code is that exactly supposed to be? doesn't look like Java to me.

Comment: If you have package A then you should have `import A` at the beginning of groovy

Comment: @daggett or rather import the class : `import packageA.classA`

Comment: there's also the question of how is that java package/class getting into the Jenkins classpath ? The normal mechanism would be to package it as a Jenkins plugin and install said plugin first. Otherwise you can look at the Groovy Grapes mechanism

Comment: @stultuske we have regular java function only . But could not able to call in Jenkins file by calling new object of class.

Comment: @Patrice imports are mentioned correctly in Jenkinsfile. We r not getting any issue there.

Comment: in regular java code, there would be some ;'es

Comment: @Stultuske yes I agree, above is just a example shared in description.sry missed the ; . Its a regular java function. Anytime,Have you tried this scenario calling java function in Jenkinsfile?

Comment: what is the actual name of your java class? Is it A or ClassA?

Comment: @Stultuske ClassA . I have updated the description for more clarity .

Comment: here you say something different: Java.class: Package A Class A : Method A

Comment: @Stultuske sry about that. It's just a example. Problem is not java code. Pls understand. Issue is calling the java function from Jenkins. Please let me know if you are successful in calling java function from Jenkinsfile?

Comment: as far as I can see, you are trying to instantiate a non-existent class from within Jenkins. yes, that's bound to give problems

Comment: Anyone Please let me know if you are successful  in calling a Java class function from Jenkinsfile.        Note- Valid Java class functions do exist in src/main/java